# Override a function call within a Django View for Testing

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Something I've been unable to find despite searching high and low...

Is it possible to override a variable or function call within a Django view?

We have some code that calls back-end C code and writes to the database. Obviously, I would want my to prevent this call from occuring within the view.

However - when I try to do a @patch... It is simply ignored and the call will occur anyway.

Is it possible to over-write this within a Django view so that I can have a return value?

Example code of what I've tried:

```
    @patch('clibs.api.create_dispute')
def test_create_dispute(self, cfunc):
    f = cfunc()
    f.return_value = 123456

    post_data = {
        'dispute_amt': ['1'],
        'id': ['12'],
    }

    request = self.factory.post(reverse('dispute:dispute_creation', args=[12]), data=post_data,HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest')
    request.user = self.user
    response = dispute_creation(request, id=12)
```

Comment: Yes of course it is possible. You're probably patching the wrong thing; see the docs on [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).

Comment: I have read this... I am patching a function though not a class... It seems not to be working. I'm calling the exact function (the function clibs.api.create_dispute).

Yet, I can still see the c code running and it returning values. I haven't been able to find working example online of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't know why you think that makes a difference. The point is, you need to patch where it is *called* - ie within your views - not where it is imported from.

Comment: So, if I patch the view... I need to assign to the variable or function call within it? It seems that's not working.

If I try to patch the variable/function call directly I will get an error the attribute doesn't exist.

What would override the function call directly?

Comment: No, please read that link again. For example, if your view was clibs/views.py, and inside that you did `from clib.api import create_dispute`, you would need to do `@patch('clib.views.create_dispute')`.

Comment: Awesome, I got it. Thank you daniel.